# how to flatten many to many relationship

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have this table and relationship.

**EDIT**

**Classes**

```
public class Person
{
  public Person()
  {
    Books = new HashSet<Book>();
  }

  public int PersonId { get; set; }
  public string fname { get; set; }
  public string lname { get; set; }
  public string Company { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
  public Book()
  {
    Persons = new HashSet<Person>();
  }

  public int BookId { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

**Class data**

```
{
  lname = "Bar", fname = "Foo", Company = "FooBar", Books = { Title = "Book1" }, { Title = "Book2" }
}
```

**Person Table**

```
+-------+-------+---------+----------+
| fname | lname | Company | PersonId |
+-------+-------+---------+----------+
| Foo   | Bar   | FooBar  | 1        |
| Bob   | Joe   | Forest  | 2        |
| Temp  | Yoo   | Temp    | 3        |
+-------+-------+---------+----------+
```

**Book Table**

```
+--------+-------+
| BookId | Title |
+--------+-------+
| 1      | Book1 |
| 2      | Book2 |
| 3      | Book3 |
+--------+-------+
```

**PersonBook Table**

```
+----------+--------+
| PersonId | BookId |
+----------+--------+
| 1        | 2      |
| 1        | 1      |
| 2        | 1      |
+----------+--------+
```

**Result**

```
+----------+---------+------+
| Name     | Company | Book |
+----------+--------+-------+
| Yoo, Temp| Temp   |       |
| Joe, Bob | Forest | Book1 |
| Bar, Foo | FooBar | Book1 |
| Bar, Foo | FooBar | Book2 |
+----------+--------+-------+
```

Now basically, Person and Book has a many-to-many relationship. I already have a Sql Query but how do I do this in a Linq Query Version?

Well, something like this:

```
select 
    (isnull(c.lname, '') + ', ' + isnull(c.fname, '')) as Name
    ,isnull(c.Company , '') as Company
    ,isnull(f.Book, '') as Book
from Person c
left join PersonBook cf
on c.PersonId = cf.PersonId
left join Book f
on f.BookId = cf.BookId
order by f.Title, c.lname
```

Any help would be much appreaciated! Thanks!

Comment: You need to show your classes as well.

Comment: Did you get a chance to check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your classes, there shouldn't be a `PersonBook` class in your model. With EF you can model many to many associations without a junction class. EF will transparently query the junction table in the database.

So your query should look like

```
var query = from p in db.People
            from b in p.Books.DefaultIfEmpty() // For a left outer join
            select new { p.fName, p.lName, p.Company, b.Title };
var result = query.asEnumerable()
                  .Select(x => new 
                    {
                        Name = string.Format("{0}, {1}", x.lName, x.fName),
                        p.Company,
                        Book = b.Title
                    }
```

If you monitor the generated SQL, you'll see that EF joins the `PersonBook` table.

Comment: Hi. You are correct, there's no `PersonBook` class. I only have two entities. I was showing it for reference, but it's a table to be exact. Thank you. I tried your query and it seems, it does not do `left join` operation.

Comment: For a left join you do `p.Books.DefaultIfEmpty()`.

Comment: Thanks mate. It solved my issue. Out of curiosity, looking at the query, how'd you know that it directly associate the keys? You didn't specify any key.

Comment: That's what EF infers from your class model. By convention it takes `PersonId` as primary key of `Person` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Left join in LINQ is a bit tricky, it requires `join into` and `DefaultIfEmpty`:

```
from p in db.People
join bj in db.Books on p.PersonId equals bj.PersonID into j
from b in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { p.fName, p.lName, p.Company, b == null ? null : b.Title }
```

Comment: How about the other version of the linq query? The one with the 'delayed-effect' query?

Comment: Delayed effect? This one will have deferred execution, if that's what you're asking about.

Comment: I see. I was talking something like this query, `People.Select(p => new .....)` Something like that.

Comment: It's just different syntax. The one provided in my answer is called syntax-based query and is transformed into method calls (including `Select` you mentioned) by compiler.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Where did `PersonBook` go? How did you select `PersonBook` table?

Comment: @BoyPasmo, The core idea of LINQ is the ability to express your query in C# (or VB) rather than in your store specific query language (SQL in this case). As part of this abstraction, when you're using LINQ, you're no longer need to think in terms of relational-database, and the `PersonBook` *is* relational-database specific. Once you query for data in your `ICollection<Book> Books` property, Entity Framework will be able to translate that into `JOIN` on the `PersonBook` table.

Comment: Hi. It's more clear to me now. Thanks. I tried your query but having this error `Expected contextual keyword 'equals'` it's point to `into j`. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: I used `==` in `join` instead of `equals`. Fixed my answer. You should try again.

Comment: In intellisense, it's not showing me the property `PersonId` in `bj.PersonId`. It's only showing me the properties of `Book`. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

This is what i have:-

```
var result = from x in (from p in persons
             join pb in personBooks
             on p.PersonID equals pb.PersonID into g
             from result1 in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new
             {
                 Name = p.lName + "," + p.fName,
                 Company = p.Company,
                 BookID = result1 == null ? 0 : result1.BookID
              })
              join y in books 
              on x.BookID equals y.BookID into g2
              from result2 in g2.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new 
              {
                  Name = x.Name,
                  Company = x.Company,
                  Book = result2 == null ? String.Empty : result2.Title
              };
```

I have used some messy range variable names, please change those in your actual query :)

Getting following result:-

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thank you. But, it seems that `personBooks` is not showing in intellisense. Did I missed anything?

Comment: @BoyPasmo - PersonBooks is a separate class right? I created a separate class & tested, Exactly same you are trying?

Comment: Actually, I am using `Code First` and it was generated as `Table` since it's a `Join Table` I don't need to create a class for `PersonBook` though it created a table `PersonBook`. I only have two classes, `Person` and `Book`

Comment: Ohk, Actually i considered the tables & their respective data in the question. If its not yet resolved you can provide the data which you are getting in `Person` & `Book` entities, I 'll give it a try:)

Comment: Can we continue here?http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67832/flatten-many-to-many-linq

Comment: I see. What data do you need mate?

Comment: Just the data you are getting in `Person` & `Book` types. I considered data what you gave for 3 tables but now since you only have data in two types I need that. Also, pardon me I can't chat on SO as its restricted at my work place.

Comment: Edited my post. Think I've given you the right one?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Linq methods, you can use SelectMany this way :

```
var PersonBook = Persons
            .SelectMany(p => p.Books,
                (p, b) =>
                    new
                    {
                        Name = p.fname + ", " + p.lname,
                        Company = p.Company,
                        BookId = b == null ? -1 : b.BookId,
                    })
              .Join(Books, p => p.BookId, b => b.BookId,
                     (p, b) =>
                         new
                         { 
                             Name = p.Name,
                             Company = p.Company,
                             Book = p.BookId == -1 ? "" : b.Title
                          });
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you! But I think it is not using `left join`. I would like to also list the `Persons` without a `Book`